# Fetching title of browser

Tags: command-line, scripting, curl, wget, url

[Fetching user title]

Seen a post prior of someone posting how to do it by single account

I wish to do this from the range 1-1000 and have it output to >> .txt

Example:

```
x@nine:~#  wget -qO- 'http://www.twitter.com/10' |  perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)(?: - twitter)?\s*<\/title/si' >> cat.txt
x@nine:~#  wget -qO- 'http://www.twitter.com/11' |  perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)(?: - twitter)?\s*<\/title/si' >> cat.txt
```

x@nine:~# cat cat.txt

```
Tweets with replies by edo (@10) on Twitter
Tweets with replies by Stephen (@11) on Twitter
```

Want it to post 1-1000

Comment: Hello and welcome tho this site! Have a look at the `seq` command to generate the sequence 1-1000.

Comment: use `curl` instead of `wget`: `curl 'http://www.twitter.com/[1-1000]' | ...`

Comment: @mosvy im getting an error whilst doing so. - "failed writing body"

Comment: try this as an example: `curl -sSL 'http://www.twitter.com/[1-12]' |  perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="</html>"}print "$1\n" if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)(?: - twitter)?\s*<\/title/si'`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a program that actually understands HTML instead of trying to parse it yourself using perl. One problem is that your perl script only parses the first instance of any title tags, not ideal for piping commands.

Below I am using [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to parse the HTML from the web pages, find all title tags, then print their content. Naturally replace 10 and 20 with the range you wanted.

```
wget -qO - https://twitter.com/{10..20} | pup 'title text{}'
```

Resulting output

```
Tweets med svar fra edo (@10) | Twitter
Tweets med svar fra Stephen (@11) | Twitter
Twitter / Konto suspendert
13 (@13) | Twitter
Hazem Emam (@14) | Twitter
Tweets med svar fra 愛と平和の伝道師 (@15) | Twitter
@16 (@16) | Twitter
Sonja Cruz (@17) | Twitter
Twitter / Konto suspendert
One God (@19) | Twitter
Twitter / Konto suspendert
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer this is what i was looking for!